# C#: Create and pass variable straight in the method call

Tags: c#, syntax

I would like to know how to declare new variable straight in the parameter brackets and pass it on like this:

```
MethodA(new int[]) //but how to fill the array if declared here? E.g. how to declare and set string?


MethodA(int[] Array)
...
```

and what if need to declare an object (class with constructor parameter)? Still possible within parameter list?

Comment: "how to declare and set string": What is the string for?

Comment: Sorry, I mean when I simply want to pass string as a parameter. Can I declare it this way?

Answer (score 7):

```
MethodA(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }); // Gives an int array pre-populated with 1,2,3
```

or

```
MethodA(new int[3]); // Gives an int array with 3 positions
```

or

```
MethodA(new int[] {}); // Gives an empty int array
```

You can do the same with strings, objects, etc:

```
MethodB(new string[] { "Do", "Ray", "Me" });

MethodC(new object[] { object1, object2, object3 });
```

If you want to pass a string through to a method, this is how you do it:

```
MethodD("Some string");
```

or

```
string myString = "My string";
MethodD(myString);
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to pass a class through to a method, you can do one of the following:

```
MethodE(new MyClass("Constructor Parameter"));
```

or

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass("Constructor Parameter");
MethodE(myClass );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
MethodA(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
```

This way you achieve the functionality you asked for.

There seems to be no way to declare a variable inside parameter list; however you can use some usual tricks like calling a method which creates and initializes the variable:

```
int[] prepareArray(int n)
{
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
    return arr;
}

...
MethodA(prepareArray(5));
...
```

With the strings, why not just use string literal:

```
MethodB("string value");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Either `new int[0]` or `new int {}` will work for you. You can also pass in values, as in `new int {1, 2, 3}`. Works for lists and other collections too.

Comment: `new string { "cat", "dog", "horse" }` - no problem. You might also look at `params` - lets you put an arbitrary number of parameters at the end of a method, as used in string.Format amongst others:

    `public Thing DoMyThing(Thing aThing, params string[] moreArgs)`

Comment: Or, using your example: `MethodA(params int[] values)` could be called by `MyClass.MethodA(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you would want to declare `MethodB(string[] strArray)` and call it as `MethodB(new string[] {"str1", "str2", "str3" })`

P.S.
I would recomment that you start with a C# tutorial, for example [this](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx) one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply mean:

`MethodA("StringValue");` ??

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: if you add the params keyword, you can simply specify multiple parameters and they will be wrapped into an array automatically:

```
void PrintNumbers(params int[] nums)
{
    foreach (int num in nums) Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
}
```

Which can then be called as:

```
PrintNumbers(1, 2, 3, 4); // Automatically creates an array.
PrintNumbers(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
PrintNumbers(new int[4]);
```